# Android Studio: Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have the followings in my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:+'
}
```

and the project gets compiled very well, but when I add the following:

```
compile 'com.mohamadamin:persianmaterialdatetimepicker:1.2.1'
```

I get this error message:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.1/support-v4-22.2.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.1/support-v4-22.2.1.jar
         file:/C:/Users/Navarch/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.1/support-v4-22.2.1.pom
         file:/C:/Users/Navarch/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.1/support-v4-22.2.1.jar
         file:/C:/Users/Navarch/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.1/support-v4-22.2.1.pom
         file:/C:/Users/Navarch/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.1/support-v4-22.2.1.jar
     Required by:
         MyApp:app:unspecified > com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1
         MyApp:app:unspecified > com.android.support:support-v13:22.1.1
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.1/support-v4-22.2.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.1/support-v4-22.2.1.jar
         file:/C:/Users/Navarch/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.1/support-v4-22.2.1.pom
         file:/C:/Users/Navarch/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.1/support-v4-22.2.1.jar
         file:/C:/Users/Navarch/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.1/support-v4-22.2.1.pom
         file:/C:/Users/Navarch/AppData/Local/Android/sdk1/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.2.1/support-v4-22.2.1.jar
     Required by:
         MyApp:app:unspecified > com.mohamadamin:persianmaterialdatetimepicker:1.2.1
```

I searched a lot but nothing seems to work for my case. How can I solve the issue?

Comment: Do the paths on your hard drive shown in the logs exist on your machine?

Comment: @CommonsWare I Checked them, no, they don't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have `appcompat-v7:22.1.1`, that means that you should have `support-v4:22.1.1`. The library you are trying to use is requesting `support-v4:22.2.1`, which is newer.

Make sure that your Android Repository is up to date in the SDK Manager. Usually, having older artifacts but not newer ones means that you have not updated the Android Repository recently.